# FORM not submitting on click of radio button in .NET Core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am attempting to submit a form on toggle(radio button).

**I am using JQuery to submit the form as follows:**

**Form:**

```
        @for (var item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
        {
        <form id="myform" action="xx" controller="xxx" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].a" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].b" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].c" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].d"  />
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].a)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].b)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[item].c)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if(Model[item].istrue)
                    {
                        <input asp-for="@Model[item].istrue" type="radio" value="@Model[item].istrue" class="form-check form-control"/> @Model[item].istrue
                        <input asp-for="@Model[item].istrue" type="radio" value="False" class="form-check form-control" />
                    }
                    else  
                    {
                        <input asp-for="@Model[item].istrue" type="radio" value="@Model[item].istrue" class="form-check form-control" /> @Model[item].istrue
                        <input asp-for="@Model[item].istrue" type="radio" value="True" class="form-check form-control" />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
@section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
        console.log("trigger works");
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
</script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult someaction(somemodel s)
{
--
--
}
```

I have placed breakpoints at the controller action which is supposed to be triggered.

The control does not go to the action

However, when toggled the `console.log` message is printed

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong!!!

**Project Link**
https://github.com/dev-agk/WebFormList

**.NET FIDDLE**
[dotnetfiddle.net/8IzLE8](http://dotnetfiddle.net/8IzLE8)

Comment: Have you checked browser console for any errors?

Comment: Yup, no console errors.

Comment: Ok and have you also confirmed the browser Network tab that no POST request is trigerred?

Comment: My understanding is, the most that can happen is that it either does not get the element or the element value is null. Both which need to show console errors. Would I be missing something obvious?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood yup confirmed no POST request being triggered

Comment: Please run console.log(document.getElementById("myform").length); What is the result of this?

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry have updated the answer, not using ID anymore using the.closest() method :)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna understood. Now, inside the click event can you say for sure that the form closest() finds is the form you intend to submit? Also, some HTML is generated by your code that you can view in the browser using page source (when right-click). Can you create a JSFiddle using the generated structure?

Comment: @LajosArpad https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IzLE8

Comment: @LajosArpad have created a .NET fiddle replication the same :)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna, Your `.NET fiddle` sample is running as a WebApp of  `ASP.NET (classic)`  instead of `ASP.NET Core`. It won't render the `<input asp-for=...>` correctly. Please try the [PR](https://github.com/dev-agk/WebFormList/pull/1/commits/30ff6eea1317e2eb9ebf0ac03097bfc6cd6b8323) with a ASP.NET Core Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several errors in your code :

Firstly, your code

```
<form id="myform" action="xx" controller="xxx" method="post">
```

will be rendered into

```
<form id="myform" action="xx" method="post">
```

Note the **action** attribute is `xx` instead of `xxx/xx`. I guess you should fix your code by using **asp-action** and **asp-controller**,e.g.:

```
<form id="myform" asp-action="MyTestActionName" asp-controller="MyTestControlerName" method="post">
```

Secondly, there're **two many forms that have the same `id`** of `myform`, it is better to assign different names for id or just remove the `id` attribute by using **`$(this).closest("form").submit()`**:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
            console.log("trigger works");
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Finally, when you write `input` TagHelper using `asp-for` :

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].a" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[item].b" />
...
```

it will be rendered into something like :

```
<input type="hidden" id="z1__a" name="[1].a" value="a1">
<input type="hidden" id="z1__a" name="[1].b" value="b1">
...
```

Note the name is **prefixed with `[1].`**. It would make it difficult to bind. Because you want to submit a single item to server, personally, I would suggest you should **rename** it by replacing your `@Model[item].` with `@item.`:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    var item = Model[i];
    <div style="border: 1px solid ;">
    <form id="myform" asp-action="Test" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.a" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.b" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.c" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.d"  />
        ...
```

Comment: tried the above and @tuanv2t's suggestion
but no luck

the onclick event is triggered but the form is not submitted

Comment: `@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function (e) {
                console.log("trigger works");
                console.log($(this).closest('form').serialize());
                $(this).closest('form').submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("submitted");
                });
            });
    </script>
}`

tried the above

serialize returns an empty string

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna The reason is you misunderstand the `submit()` method. In your code, **you are actually binding a `submit` event handler** by `.submit(function(){...})`, if you want to **trigger a submit event**, you need change it to be `.submit()` **with no arguments**.

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna I test your code and create a PR, if you have any further question, please feel free to update me.

Comment: thanks for the above, did not know it, but the problem is the `.submit()` event handler is not being triggered

Comment: [Inline Link] (dotnetfiddle.net/8IzLE8) have added for ease :)

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna Do you mean you tried my [PR](https://github.com/dev-agk/WebFormList/pull/1/commits/30ff6eea1317e2eb9ebf0ac03097bfc6cd6b8323) and still get the same results?

Comment: tried the PR and it works, however, the same code is not working in my actual app.
will accept the above answer now and try to localize my problem :)
in my project `$(this),closest('form').serialize()` returns an empty string.

Comment: @AbhilashGopalakrishna My best guess is that the `this` points to an incorrect input element. Could you please try `console.log(this)` to check whether it references the correct element?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Abhilash Gopalakrishna,

I suggest to make 2 changes 
1: Make a partial view for each item ( contain form for each item)
2: Idea to identify each myform element to make radio button trigger its correct item.

Depend on your business, the Guid could be the ID of the model item.

Could you have a look at my demo for this case at : https://bitbucket.org/tuanv2t/net-core-demo/src/master/NetCoreDemo/WebItemOfListDemo/

Comment: Not able to access the demo:)

Comment: A wonderful method to keep the code clean and I believe it makes it easier because of the control cycle of a partial view

But still I am facing the same error, so will not accept the answer as of now

But really a wonderful method!!!

thank you :)

Comment: @tuwnv2t
made some changes to the above
`@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
            console.log($(this).closest('form').serialize());
            $(this).closest('form').submit(function (e) {
                alert("submitted");
            });
        });
    </script>
}`

script in a partial view is not convention , 
added the above in index  ,

here the form value we get ,
but the form isnt submitted.

Comment: @tuwnv2t have borrowed your project, hope its okay :)